# How to trigger Fn + F8 using a script?

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui, pynput

I have tried `pyautogui`, `pynput`, and `keyboard` PyPI Packages. I want to trigger Fn + F8 key using python script. The below code is not working...

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('fn+f8')
```

Please suggest any other technique to trigger fn + f8 using any script. It shouldn't be manual intervention...

Answer (score 1):

according to the [Documentation of PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions), you should be able to do that using:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('fn')
pyautogui.press('f8')
pyautogui.keyUp('fn')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering..but the thing is that it is not triggering the fn + f8. It is only triggering f8 key only.....

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-hotkey-function), it's already in pyautogui.

```
from pyautogui import hotkey

hotkey('fn', 'F8')
```

This worked on every system I tried it on.

Comment: Thanks for Answering....But it is not working in my ubuntu and windows system...

Comment: @SKSarfarazALI does your regular keyboard trigger it? How do you check if it's being triggered?

Comment: fn+f5 is simply disabling my touchpad.But it is not doing same when doing it by pyautogui.

Comment: @SKSarfarazALI Consider using the `pydirectinput` module, from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/). `pydirectinput` does not have a hotkey function, so use the other answer (`keyDown(), press, keyUp`).

Comment: Thanks for answering @Codeman. But here also the fn key is also not working.....I came to know that the fn key has no scan code that's why it is not possible to invoke the fn key using python script.